# Firefox still starts full screen

Tags: unity, firefox, 11.10

I thought that this bug should be solved in oneiric beta 2.
But i still have this problem with firefox, thunderbird etc.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. If you start an application and it takes up 75% or more of the screen, it will automatically be opened maximized.

You can change that auto-maximize value with the CompizConfig Settings Manager (command `ccsm` from the `compizconfig-settings-manager` package) in the options for the *Ubuntu Unity Plugin*:

[image]

If you set it to 100, Unity won't change anything, if you set it to 0, it will try to start all windows maximized.

Comment: You have this answered already some where, I just saw it around.

Comment: This behavior may make sense on small screens, like netbooks, but if the resolution is about or higher than 1680x1050 to begin with automaximize should be disabled in my opinion.